# How to detect whether a printer is connected or not?

Tags: c#, windows

How to detect the whether a printer is installed in my PC or not and whether the printer connection is active or not?

Answer (score 2):

This class will list all the printer installed and give you the status of the printer.

```
using System;
using System.Management;

public class MyClass
{

      static void printProps(ManagementObject o,string prop){
            try{Console.WriteLine(prop+"|"+o[prop]);}catch(Exception e){Console.Write(e.ToString());}
      }

      [STAThread]
      static void Main(string[] args) 
      {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new 
        ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer where Default=True");

        string printerName = "";
        foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get()){
          printerName = printer["Name"].ToString().ToLower();
            Console.WriteLine("Printer :"+printerName);
            printProps(printer, "WorkOffline");
            //Console.WriteLine();
            switch( Int32.Parse( printer["PrinterStatus"].ToString() )){
                  case 1: Console.WriteLine("Other"); break;
                  case 2: Console.WriteLine("Unknown");break;
                  case 3: Console.WriteLine("Idle"); break;
                  case 4: Console.WriteLine("Printing"); break;
                  case 5: Console.WriteLine("Warmup"); break;
                  case 6: Console.WriteLine("Stopped printing"); break;
                  case 7: Console.WriteLine("Offline"); break;
            }
        }
      }
}
```