# How can I check if a printer is physically connected into my PC?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

I built an EPOS application where it prints receipt if the printer is connected to my PC via USB port. The problem is if the printer is not physically connected then the document will be pending (as shown in the screenshot).

[image]

My question:

How can I check if the printer is physically connected (plugged) into my PC?

I already seen those questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617200/how-to-detect-printer-is-connect-or-not-using-c-sharp-2008) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710810/check-printer-if-connected-to-pc-or-not) and the answers are not helpful because non of them mentioned how to check if the printer is physically connected but they only list all the printers names and some other information.

Anyone knows how to do that? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean _literally_ physically connected or just "online".  Physically connected printers can still be offline and network printers can be online.

Answer (score 2):

check [`PrintQueue.IsOffline Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.isoffline.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know if a printer is physically connected to your PC is by physically checking the connection. This isn't a Pun, its an actual answer...

Comment: in windows you can check whether device is connected or not so it should be possible to check it programmatically